# Error trying to convert tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.BatchDataset to a Tensor

Tags: tensorflow, tensor, valueerror

I'm new on this platform and new in the tensor-stuff world.

First the context:
I'm trying to process an audio for the prediction phase. We (my team and I) tested the code in a Jupyter Notebook, and everything worked ok.

But, when I moved the code to the project itself, the prediction function throw me the following error:

```
`ValueError: Attempt to convert a value (<BatchDataset element_spec=(TensorSpec(shape=(None, None, 2), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(None, 2), dtype=tf.float32, name=None))>) with an unsupported type (<class 'tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.BatchDataset'>) to a Tensor.`
```

We saw this error before when we were working on the jupyter-nb, and we solved it by "squeezing" the sample, I mean, by adding this line:
`sample_squeezed = tf.squeeze(sample_slices)`

(Note: sample_slices type -> tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.BatchDataset)

But now, I can't perform tf.squeeze over sample_slices (even when the code hasn't changed). What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!